# Prove there is no an Analytic Centre Manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, dynamical-systems

I must prove that the differential equation below does not have an analytic centre manifold:

$$
\dot{x}=x^3,
\dot{y}=2y-2x^2
$$

I try:

The linearisation of the system at the origin is:
$$\dot{x}=DX(0)x=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x \\
y
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

and find the eigenvalues with the corresponding eigenvectors:

$\lambda_1=0$: $(1,0)$

$\lambda_2=2$: $(0,1)$

and from the Centre Manifold Theorem, I find that there exist locally a centre manifold containing the origin, and tangent to the vector $(1,0)$ at the origin.

My question is, then... How do I prove that I can not find it analytically?

The orbits of my system are:
$$
\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}=\frac{2y-2x^2}{x^3}
$$

Have I understood correctly the problem?
What should I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking for analytic functions $y(x)=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0}a_nx^n$ such that  $$x^3y'(x)=2(y(x)-x^2),$$ and $y(0)=y'(0)=0$, one gets the conditions $a_0=a_{2n+1}=0$  for every $n\geqslant0$, $a_2=1$, and $a_{2n+2}=na_{2n}$ for every $n\geqslant1$, hence $$y(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}n!\,x^{2n+2}.$$ The radius of convergence of this series is zero hence the center manifold is not analytic at $(0,0)$.

streamplot[{x^3,2y−2x^2},{x,-2,2},{y,-1,2}]

[image: Phase plane]